# How to hide an object in the viewport but still be selectable?

Tags: 3d-view, visibility

Thought the answer for this was straightforward, but that approach isn't working.

For the Doorway.013 object you can see that 'Show in Viewports' has been unchecked, but 'Selectable' is still checked. However I can't actually select the object and move it, etc. Is there another toggle somewhere to make it work?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, maybe what you want is something like Viewport Display (under the Visibility options) > Display as > Wire, in that case you'll only see a wire

Comment: It's currently set to a Wireframe display, but I'm trying to hide the wires. I'd prefer that object to not be visible, but still be able to move that group around.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/ltdbbc/

This appears to replace the 'transparency' option in previous versions of blender.